# Recommended to apply but ghosted by HR

Tags: professionalism, communication, hiring

I have a personal connection who is relatively senior at a company. He thought I would be suitable for a role and recommended I forward a cover letter and cv to their GM of HR (after clearing it with said GM internally).

Two weeks on I've received nothing at all in response. No confirmation of receipt, no introductory response, not even a 'thanks, no thanks.'

What action should I take at this point, if any? It could simply have fallen off the radar or they could be not at all interested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: If I was totally unconcerned about answer quality on SE I would probably post a meme picture of Mel Gibson in Braveheart and his repeated instruction to "HOOOLD". But I am, so I won't.

Comment: Probably time for a simple followup. 2 weeks is a little white to receive nothing, cause it sounds like a somewhat senior role given the GM of HR is involved, so I'm a bit surprised there hasn't been a receipt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I hasn't applied for a specific role, I sent a polite follow up from the perspective of requesting feedback on my EoI.

Feels strange to answer my own question as "right" but I feel like neither of the answers were quite there in that one assumed I wasn't in contact with my pc and the other assumed I'd applied for a specific role.

Comment: "and the other assumed I'd applied for a specific role." Well, you did say: "He thought I would be suitable for a role" so it's not far-fetched to think that your connection was thinking of a specific role.

Answer (score 7):

Simply refer back to your personal connection and work from there.

Since your connection has the inside track, he should be able to provide some kind of clarity as to what the current situation is.

It might well be that the role isn't actually open for recruiting for yet, or there might be a breakdown in communication somewhere.

Your connection is the only person who can really chase this up, having the context.

Answer (score 4):

Two weeks is a short time in the world of contemporary HR staff. The typical HR staffer will review hundreds of resumes and come up with a 'short list' of candidates. Then that list gets passed to the hiring manager for evaluation. After selection, HR does their follow up and contacts the candidates.

A polite follow up with HR is definitely in order. That confirms your interest in the position.

This is also a good time to touch base with your company connection; see if they have any visibility into the evaluation / selection process. Are *you* on the short list? Where is the hiring manager in the selection process?

Comment: You deserve a +1 just for the username

Comment: The point of referrals like OP is describing is to expedite the process. Recommendations from senior staff are treated differently than resumes from complete strangers.